# Selinux denials while trying to open camera device when targeting to Android 10

Tags: java, android, android-camera2, selinux

Device: Oneplus 7 Pro, Android 10. My app uses Camera2 api to open camera device and capture photo (actually, that's one of libraries, not app itself). As long as I'm targeting to api 28, all is fine. But after changing target api to 29, it freezes due to selinux denials:

> 2019-10-22 11:32:17.734 4305-4305/? I/CameraManagerGlobal: Connecting
>   to camera service 2019-10-22 11:32:17.726 4305-4305/? W/my.app:
>   type=1400 audit(0.0:44232): avc: denied { read } for
>   name="u:object_r:persist_camera_prop:s0" dev="tmpfs" ino=17156
>   scontext=u:r:untrusted_app_27:s0:c120,c257,c512,c768
>   tcontext=u:object_r:persist_camera_prop:s0 tclass=file permissive=0
>   2019-10-22 11:32:17.726 4305-4305/? W/my.app: type=1400
>   audit(0.0:44233): avc: denied { read } for
>   name="u:object_r:persist_camera_prop:s0" dev="tmpfs" ino=17156
>   scontext=u:r:untrusted_app_27:s0:c120,c257,c512,c768
>   tcontext=u:object_r:persist_camera_prop:s0 tclass=file permissive=0
>   2019-10-22 11:32:17.738 4305-4305/? E/libc: Access denied finding
>   property "vendor.camera.aux.packagelist" 2019-10-22 11:32:17.738
>   4305-4305/? I/chatty: uid=10376(my.app) identical 1 line 2019-10-22
>   11:32:17.738 4305-4305/? E/libc: Access denied finding property
>   "vendor.camera.aux.packagelist" 2019-10-22 11:32:17.738 4305-4305/?
>   W/CameraManagerGlobal: [soar.cts] ignore the status update of camera:
>   2 2019-10-22 11:32:17.738 4305-4305/? E/libc: Access denied finding
>   property "vendor.camera.aux.packagelist" 2019-10-22 11:32:17.738
>   4305-4305/? W/CameraManagerGlobal: [soar.cts] ignore the status update
>   of camera: 3 2019-10-22 11:32:17.739 4305-4305/? E/libc: Access denied
>   finding property "vendor.camera.aux.packagelist" 2019-10-22
>   11:32:17.739 4305-4305/? W/CameraManagerGlobal: [soar.cts] ignore the
>   status update of camera: 4 2019-10-22 11:32:17.726 4305-4305/?
>   W/my.app: type=1400 audit(0.0:44234): avc: denied { read } for
>   name="u:object_r:persist_camera_prop:s0" dev="tmpfs" ino=17156
>   scontext=u:r:untrusted_app_27:s0:c120,c257,c512,c768
>   tcontext=u:object_r:persist_camera_prop:s0 tclass=file permissive=0
>   2019-10-22 11:32:17.739 4305-4305/? E/libc: Access denied finding
>   property "vendor.camera.aux.packagelist" 2019-10-22 11:32:17.739
>   4305-4305/? W/CameraManagerGlobal: [soar.cts] ignore the status update
>   of camera: 5 2019-10-22 11:32:17.739 4305-4305/? E/libc: Access denied
>   finding property "vendor.camera.aux.packagelist" 2019-10-22
>   11:32:17.739 4305-4535/? E/libc: Access denied finding property
>   "vendor.camera.aux.packagelist" 2019-10-22 11:32:17.726 4305-4305/?
>   W/my.app: type=1400 audit(0.0:44235): avc: denied { read } for
>   name="u:object_r:persist_camera_prop:s0" dev="tmpfs" ino=17156
>   scontext=u:r:untrusted_app_27:s0:c120,c257,c512,c768
>   tcontext=u:object_r:persist_camera_prop:s0 tclass=file permissive=0

So it looks like SELinux prevents my app from using the camera hardware. Any ideas why?